# Showing APK are required to have a privacy policy set Playstore

Tags: android

This is my first time to upload apk on play store. Firstly, I am getting error of **Privacy policy** that I have use camera in my app. Later on I searched on google I got some some suggestion later on again I creating signed apk and when I going to upload apk its showing this error.

> Store listing
>   1 task to complete before you rollout
>   Your app has an apk with version code 1 that requests the following permission(s): android.permission.CAMERA. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.

Is it possible to upload apk without upload url of Privacy policy. I used camera in my app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Is it possible to upload apk without upload url of Privacy policy.**

**NO**, You must Add **`URL`** on Privacy Section. It's Google's Policy.
You can host your **privacy policy with any publicly accessible URL** .

Read official guideline about [**`Privacy Policy Guidance`**](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/privacy-policy-guide)

> Since February 2017 Google enforces a strict privacy policy
>   requirement on apps requesting sensitive permissions and user data.
>   There are quite a few places in the Google Play Store documentation
>   that points out that requirement.

**What information do you share?**

> In your policy, you should disclose the circumstances when you share
>   information. For example, you may share information with third parties
>   as part of the service (like a restaurant reservation Action), with
>   other users (like a social network or forum), with marketing partners,
>   or with service providers that assist with your service (like hosting
>   companies or technology platforms).

Comment: its necessary to add privacy policy url ? any other method without url ?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Whenever This message arrive you must add PRIVACY RULE .

Comment: its means i must have to add privacy policy url ? @Amiya

Comment: @Abhishekkumar yes . Its a Google's additional feature !

Comment: i dont have idea , where to find the format of privacy policy text , i used camera in my app then how can i make document of privacy policy , where i have to upload .please help me

Comment: @Abhishekkumar cool . Check  demo http://www.forcempower.com/android-privacy-policy/ .

Comment: @Abhishekkumar goto https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/privacy-policy-guide then read `Use Google Sites for a Privacy Policy`

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Solved this yet ?

Comment: yes, solved now i successfully uploaded apk Thankyou so much.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Glad to hear .Move ahead .

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using user's camera, google will allow you to upload apps only if you are sure you are not abusing the access to the camera.

In Play console, go to **Store Presence > Store Listing > Find Privacy policy** at the end of the page.

Then place the url of the page of your privacy policy and you are good to go.

Comment: One thing more previously i uploaded my signed apk successfully but now when i again generated signed apk  its sowing version code 1 with issue & i am not able to upload apk.

Comment: You just place the link to your privacy policy and you can upload new apks.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar maybe you just need to increase your version code?!

Comment: @Abhishekkumar use `versionCode 2` in the file `build.gradle`

Comment: yes this issue solved , one more thing , can you please tell me without privacy policy url may i publish apk(I used camera in my app)

Answer (score 3):

**No it is not possible to upload apk without upload url of Privacy policy**

There is small [service](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/), can be used for fast generation of Privacy Policy in simple cases.